# How expensive is Runtime.getRuntime() in combination with getting the memory metrics

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-management

How performance intense is Runtime.getRuntime() in combination with getting the memory metrics (free memory, used memory, etc.). I am considering using it to monitor memory consumption in the application to troubleshoot a memory problem on production code, but I'm wondering if it will be an expensive process that slows down the response of the web application.  Let's say for example if you are using in a polling fashion.  If you poll let's say every 5 seconds for example or every minute.  Will this have a significant impact on the application?

Comment: And how do you intend to use it to monitor "memory consumption"? Of what, anyway? Your application? Have you ever considered using JMX?

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime()` itself is practically zero cost, but that doesn't seem to be what you're actually asking.

Comment: Yes I was intending to use it to calculate the memory the application is using.  I was intending to use the freeMemory, maxMemory and do whatever calculations are necessary to determine the memory usage. Whenever it reaches a certain point send out a notification, log it or whatever is reasonable.  I was just wondering if those processes were expensive as in consuming a lot of processing time.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out EJP.  I have edited my question summary to better explain my question.

Comment: fge, I briefly looked at JMX after you pointed out but so far that seems like it requires a lot more time and effort than I have available for this at the moment.  It seems that way. Does it take a lot of time and effort to set up and implement for gaging the memory usage of the applicaiton or am I overestimating the effort?.

Comment: Give us some context on your application.  Setting up JMX is pretty routine if it's a Spring or SpringBoot application.  If it's something else, it can still be added, but you are using vanilla-integration with JMX.  Instructions would depend on your situation.

Comment: @JeffBennett this post is so old I couldn't really tell you much about it anymore.  At the time I was working in Java and the application was using some legacy servlets.  No spring.  It was using servlets with a home grown MVC architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The performance is essentially the same, because the essentially the same thing is happening in both cases.

One drawback -
If the child gets stuck in a loop or is generally sloppy with resource management, the parent suffers too.

Performance will be the same.

Comment: on what reputative source is your answer based? And what do you mean by child and parent? I'm asking whether it is expensive to repeatedly run the freeMemory(), maxMemory() and totalMemory() methods.